# Eliminar .0 en los valores de una columna de un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos

estoy trabajando con un dataframe de un e-commerce (extraido de Kaggle), y lo que quisiera hacer es simplemente agregarle una letra a la columna de ID, ej: que la columna de costumer_id que es [1,2,3,4,5] pase a ser [1c,2c,3c,4c,5c].
El problema esta en que para sumarle la c a los valores de la columna los tengo que transformar en str y al hacerlo me convierte los numeros en .0, ej [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0], quisiera encontrar una forma de poder eliminar esos dos ultimos caracteres que se agregan, ya que cuando uso replace para eliminar el ".0", algunos valores me quedan mal por ejemplo el 10 que pasa a ser simplemente 1.

Adjunto los comando que use y el link de la base de datos de kaggle.

> [Cita en bloque](https://www.kaggle.com/ruchi798/shopping-cart-database?select=customers.csv)

```
df_customers["customer_id"] = df_customers["customer_id"].astype(str)
    
df_customers["customer_id"] = df_customers["customer_id"].replace({'[.]':''}, regex=True)
    
df_customers["customer_id"] = df_customers["customer_id"] + "c"
```

Luego de usar estos comandos me queda todo multiplicado por 10 que tampoco es mi idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convierte la columna en integer antes de pasarla a string:

```
df_customers["customer_id"] = df_customers["customer_id"].astype(int).astype(str) + 'c'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! no me di cuenta ‍♂️